# A Starting Menu for a simple game

Tags: java, menu

I am making this small and simple game with Java, and when I start it up, it just starts the game without any menus or something. Now, I want to make it so that if I run the game, there comes a game menu, or starting menu, where you can select new game, and exit. But, how would I do this? I need some help with this.

Edit:

The game is in a 800x600 screen, and I want like, a menu that takes over the whole 800x600 screen, with just a "Start Game" and a "Exit" button.

Comment: Please clearify if you want a menu-bar (at the top of the screen) or some sort of window/screen with some buttons (e.g. vertically aligned)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Swing tutorial on menus](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html) will be an excellent reference for you as you work through creating a menu.

Here is some sample code for creating a simple menu like you described, assuming your JFrame is called `frame`.

```
//Where the GUI is created:
JMenuBar menuBar;
JMenu menu;
JMenuItem menuItem;

//Create the menu bar.
menuBar = new JMenuBar();

//Build the first menu.
menu = new JMenu("File");
menu.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_F);
menu.getAccessibleContext().setAccessibleDescription(
        "File menu");
menuBar.add(menu);

//JMenuItems show the menu items
menuItem = new JMenuItem("New",
                         new ImageIcon("images/new.gif"));
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_N);
menu.add(menuItem);

// add a separator
menu.addSeparator();

menuItem = new JMenuItem("Pause", new ImageIcon("images/pause.gif"));
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_P);
menu.add(menuItem);

menuItem = new JMenuItem("Exit", new ImageIcon("images/exit.gif"));
menuItem.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_E);
menu.add(menuItem);

// add menu bar to frame
frame.setJMenuBar(theJMenuBar);
```

The important classes to know are [JMenuBar](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html), [JMenu](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html), and [JMenuItem](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuItem.html).

To handle clicks on those menu items, you need to add an [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) for each, using code such as:

```
menuItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { // ...});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass JFrame, add two JButtons to it and show that frame when needed.

Comment: 1)  Sub-classing `JFrame` is rarely necessary or desirable.  2) Most apps. would only have one `JFrame`, popping a (possibly modal) `JDialog` or `JOptionPane` or (less likely) `JWindow`.  3)  In this case, the two buttons might better be contained in a `CardLayout` within the main GUI.  4) A `JButton` is not a 'menu'.

Comment: @Andrew: I interpret "game menu" as a fullscreen view with some buttons (new game, load game, credits), but I agree that a "menu" is generally some sort of bar at the top of the window/screen. Lacking any further information I just guessed ;)

Comment: Fair enough re. point 4.  Feel free to edit your question to reflect the other 3.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Set a `JMenuBar` to the `JFrame` (or `JApplet`).  Add `JMenu(s)` to the `JMenuBar`.  Add `JMenuItem(s)` to the `JMenu(s)`.  Add `ActionListener(s)` to the `JMenuItem(s)`.

Google 'java+tutorial+classname' for more details of each.